# Firebase emulator infinite compiling and function call for a NextJS hello world example on macOS

Tags: firebase, macos, google-cloud-functions, next.js, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to use firebase emulators on my Mac to run a simple NextJS hello world program. It's literally a hello world example. I'm forwarding all host requests to a function that I wrote, as bellow:

```js
const { join } = require('path')
const { https } = require('firebase-functions')
const { default: next } = require('next')

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const nextjsDistDir = require('./next.config.js').distDir

const nextjsServer = next({
  dev: isDev,
  conf: {
    distDir: nextjsDistDir,
  },
})
const nextjsHandle = nextjsServer.getRequestHandler()

exports.nextjs = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return nextjsServer.prepare().then(() => {
    nextjsHandle(req, res)
  })
})
```

And here is how my package.json file looks like:

```js
{
  "name": "firebase-boilerplate",
  "main": "server.js",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "serve": "next build && firebase emulators:start --only functions,hosting --project 123"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
    "next": "^10.0.5",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

and like I said, the page I'm trying to load is like this:

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

// import {app} from '../services/firebase';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>Hello World </>
  )
}
```

Now, when I run this on my mac with "nom run serve", emulators boot up ok, but the moment it try to access localhost:5000/index it keeps compiling and calling my "NextJS" function and eventually leads to timeout. Occasionally though, I do get the "Hello World" output, but only after so much computation, and only occasionally. What exactly is wrong? Is fb emulator not a reliable software or not working for Mac? OR I'm missing something?

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be issues with the Firebase Emulator and Next.JS. As per [1](https://github.com/jthegedus/firebase-functions-next-example#importa) you could try to make sure that you are using Node 6.11.5 and test. But most importantly I believe that you should have two projects (one for development and one for production) and test things first live on your deployed Cloud Function on the development project and then launch to production, rather than using the emulator. Check [more details on this other repository](https://github.com/LarvenLLC/functions-nextjs#caveats).

Comment: some updates: when I replace the code inside "onRequest" with something like : res.send("Hello World!"), this works, I have a feeling that my code inside that function lacks something, perhaps we need to do something like res.end() somewhere, although, every code I checked is exactly like what I did.

Comment: Thanks @DanielOcando, I can't start directly with a dev project in firebase before testing it on emulator, the reasons is if by any chance I do some recursive call due to a bug, I will be charged for an infinite amount of money! And that is risky. By the way, why to use such an old version of nodejs? Do you see anything wrong in my code by the way?

Comment: I don't think node6 is necessary, that is an old link, firebase doc actually recommends node8+. The issue must have been something else.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if your issue is with the next.js configuration or the code itself, as I don't see any evident issues with it. It might also be a problem with the emulator, in which case I'd advise you to open an issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) to get any further assistance.